# Modifying parameters passed to external url form with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I need to include an external search form in my main layout view, such that it is displayed with every page render. At the moment, in my layouts/main.html.erb I have:

```
<div style="float: right";>
<% form_tag url_for("http://search.example.co.uk/search"), {:method => :get} do %>
<%= text_field_tag(:q) %>
<%= select_tag(:category, '<option value="all">All</option> <option value="dogs">Dogs</option> <option value="cats">Cats</option>') %>
<%= hidden_field_tag("site", "Example") %>
<%= hidden_field_tag("btnG", "Search") %>
<%= hidden_field_tag("filter", "0")  %>
<%= hidden_field_tag("proxystylesheet", "std_stylesheet") %>
<%= submit_tag "Search" %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

This currently works, and in the header of all pages rendering the main layout, I have a text field, a drop down and a Search button. On clicking the 'Search' button, the page is directed to http://search.example.co.uk/search with all the parameters.

I need to be able to modify the parameters before the page is redirected. I need to concatenate params[:q] and params[:category] and pass this with the redirection. Is this possible?

Thanks for any help/suggestions.

Comment: Did you consider submitting the form to a controller action and redirecting from there? You're already submitting this form using GET, so that will probably work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do this by submitting your form to an action which would concatenate all your results and they would in-turn redirect your request to the URL which you have specified along with the parameters that you have processed...